# XSD arbitrary but fix number of elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XSD file:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="list">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence><!--arbitrary number of log entries-->
                <xsd:element name="vocable" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><!--a log entry is     a complex type-->
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="firstLanguageTranslations" type="xsd:string"     minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                        <xsd:element name="firstLanguagePhoneticScripts" type="xsd:string"     minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                        <xsd:element name="secondLanguageTranslations" type="xsd:string"     minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                        <xsd:element name="secondLanguagePhoneticScripts" type="xsd:string"     minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />

                        <xsd:element name="topics" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"     maxOccurs="1" />
                        <xsd:element name="chapters" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"     maxOccurs="1" />
                        <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"     maxOccurs="1" />
                        <xsd:element name="learnLevel" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"     maxOccurs="1" />
                        <xsd:element name="relevanceLevel" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"     maxOccurs="1" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Now I want to change it, so that in the inner most sequence, there are element pairs of `<key>attribute name</key>` and `<value>value</value>`, so that in my program, I can simply add new attributes. However, I want those attributes to be the same for each vocable element. How do I assure that in the XSD file?

I'll list the requirements of the XSD file to make it more clear:

1. The XML file can contain an arbitrary number of vocables
2. A vocable can consist of an arbitrary number of attributes
3. The attributes of a vocable are the same for all vocables (same amount, same keys)
4. The attributes are represented using `<key>attribute name</key>` and `<value>attribute value</value>`

If the use of a key and a value element is not the best way to do this, I am open to other suggestions.

**EDIT#1**:
To make it even clearer, I'll add two examples:
Shall be valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<list>
    <vocable>
        <key>firstLanguageTranslation</key>
        <value>word1</value>
        <key>secondLanguageTranslation</key>
        <value>word2</value>
    </vocable>
    <vocable>
        <key>firstLanguageTranslation</key>
        <value>word1</value>
        <key>secondLanguageTranslation</key>
        <value>word2</value>
   </vocable>
</list>
```

Also valid, because vocables have the same attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<list>
    <vocable>
        <key>firstLanguageTranslation</key>
        <value>word1</value>
        <key>secondLanguageTranslation</key>
        <value>word2</value>
        <key>something</key>
        <value>word4</value>
    </vocable>
    <vocable>
        <key>firstLanguageTranslation</key>
        <value>word1</value>
        <key>secondLanguageTranslation</key>
        <value>word2</value>
        <key>something</key>
        <value>word3</value>
   </vocable>
</list>
```

Shall not be valid, because the vocables don't have the same attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<list>
    <vocable>
        <key>firstLanguageTranslation</key>
        <value>word1</value>
        <key>secondLanguageTranslation</key>
        <value>word2</value>
    </vocable>
    <vocable>
        <key>firstLanguageTranslation</key>
        <value>word1</value>
        <key>secondLanguageTranslation</key>
        <value>word2</value>
        <key>something else</key>
        <value>word3</value>
   </vocable>
</list>
```

**EDIT#2**:

Why this is important for me:

I want the user to be able to add (or delete) attributes to the vocables in my program as they see fit, because different people have different expectations and opinions about what should be saved in a vocable. I want  to do that without having to write code to manually change the XSD file every time the user adds an attribute.
At the same time, I want to be able to let the user choose, which attributes of a vocable will be shown in a table of vocables. This is much easier, when I know, that every vocable has a specific attribute.

Comment: "If the use of a key and a value element is not the best way to do this, I am open to other suggestions." Does that mean you are in charge of designing this XML format? If so, yes, you should reconsider the `key` / `value` pairs - they really make the document more complicated than it needs to be. Let me know if you'd like me to explain alternative designs. Can you use XML Schema 1.1?

Comment: @MathiasMüller I am completely in charge of the XML Schema Definition and the XML file etc. Please explain it to me : ) I think I can use 1.1, not sure what the difference between 1.1 and others is.

Comment: I'll add an answer in a moment. In the meantime, to test whether you can use XML Schema 1.1, use a construct that is exclusive to XSD 1.1, e.g. the `xs:assert` (explanations [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/), section "Assertions"). I'll also explain why the version matters so much.

Comment: It matter, because I need to be able to process all the vocables in the XML file the same way. If they don't have the same attributes and not even the same number of attributes, then there is no way of knowing what attributes for example should be searched for an occurrence of a string.

Seems lxml etree can't deal with XSD 1.1. It tells me parse error.

Comment: In XSD 1.0, there is absolutely no means for such a constraint on your documents. I suggest you take a very different approach: Make the schema a _rigid_ one, listing all possible "attributes" (attributes are actually something else in XML) explicitly. Make some of them optional if needed and make sure the order is consistent (only if they are encoded as elements). If there are `vocable` elements which have nothing in common, well, why do they have the same name? A schema language is not meant to deal with arbitrariness.

Comment: I think that is a good suggestion and I might do that instead. Thank you for your work on this question and for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Schema Design**

Regarding your XML design, everything looks fine, except for the `key` and `value` elements. Imagine, for instance, that someone would want to *select* the value of `secondLanguageTranslation` from such a document. In XPath, they would have to do something along the lines of

```
/list/vocable/key[. = 'secondLanguageTranslation']/following-sibling::value[1]
```

which is quite a long statement! Now, let us assume the document was the following:

```
<list>
    <vocable>
        <firstLanguageTranslation>word1</firstLanguageTranslation>
        <secondLanguageTranslation>word2</secondLanguageTranslation>
    </vocable>
</list>
```

Given this new document, the same information can be retrieved with a much simpler XPath expression:

```
/list/vocable/secondLanguageTranslation
```

Which is easier to read, even though the element names are a bit long (highly subjective). To make my point a more general one: in XML, elements do not only *contain* information, they *are* information, in the sense that an element's name is itself information. To be crystal-clear, in a structure like

```
<key>secondLanguage</key>
```

the `key` element is nothing more than a container for a name, whereas in

```
<secondLanguage>word1</secondLanguage>
```

the element name has clear-cut semantics, unlike the `key`element, which contains any name. Alternatively, keys and values are easy to represent as attributes:

```
<vocable secondLanguageTranslation="word1"/>
```

especially if the content of keys and values only ever is single words.

**Ensuring all elements have the same, arbitrary set of elements**

That said, I think I understand why you would like to introduce `key` and `value` - because then, changes to the documents would not require you to change the schema document. But also, it means that you lose control over the document content - all you know is that valid documents contain `key` and `value` elements. And controlling the structure and content of documents is exactly what XML Schema is for. If your document is constantly evolving, perhaps no XML Schema is of much use.

Still, taking the `key` and `value` structure seriously, ensuring that all instances of elements have the same content can be done with *assertions*. An assertion to make sure that all `vocable` elements have the same number of `key` elements could be the following:

```
<xsd:assert test="every $x in vocable satisfies (if ($x/following-sibling::vocable) then count($x/key) = count($x/following-sibling::vocable[1]/key) else true())"/>
```

and the rule which compares the keys of all `vocable` elements:

```
<xsd:assert test="every $x in vocable satisfies (if ($x/following-sibling::vocable) then (every $y in $x/key satisfies $y = $x/following-sibling::vocable[1]/key) else true())"/>
```

embedded into a complete schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="list">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="vocable" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="vocableType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:assert test="every $x in vocable satisfies (if ($x/following-sibling::vocable) then count($x/key) = count($x/following-sibling::vocable[1]/key) else true())"/>
            <xsd:assert test="every $x in vocable satisfies (if ($x/following-sibling::vocable) then (every $y in $x/key satisfies $y = $x/following-sibling::vocable[1]/key) else true())"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="vocableType">
        <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="key" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

The assertion must take place in the definition of `list` because assertions inside individual `vocable` elements can only access subtrees taking themselves as the root. Assertions are only possible in XSD 1.1, and this kind of rule is completely out of the question in XSD 1.0.

As you can see, this kind of expression is hard to read - can you clarify *why* you really need to ensure all `vocable` elements have the same content? Especially because you seem to be quite content with not knowing which keys will be present in the documents.

Comment: I see, it's highly complex with those assertions : /

And `lxml` doesn't support `XSD 1.1`, unfortunately. I was already wondering how it should be possible with a tree-like structure to assure something about sibling elements, so it makes sense to me, if you say it is not possible in `XSD 1.0`.
The alternatives are to either let vocables have arbitrary attributes, independent of other vocables or limit the attributes to an initial set of attributes, which I have done before. Sometimes I thought "What if someone else doesn't think in my categories and wants another attribute added / instead?"

Comment: @Zelphir XML Schema is usually used to filter input documents - and only accept those that the application is prepared to process. If you do not need to filter (e.g. because your application (Python?) can process any values inside `vocable`) then perhaps you do not need a schema at all*? In general, there is nothing wrong with making others think in your categories (because there is an awful lot of categories to think in and it's hard to account for all of them in your code :-). *Or only a very loose schema, that is.

Comment: True, I wouldn't really need the schema, but I like to validate before  writing back the whole XML content, so that I can be sure my program made no mistake in changing vocable stuff. Also maybe I'd have to add validation later on anyway, if I implement some network functionality (if my project ever gets that far). For example a user could connect to another one and they could ask each other like in a quiz/test. Or vocable lists could be shared on some server.

Comment: @Zelphir Now that I've read the second edit to your post, one last comment: I still think that most users will be happy to choose from a set of predefined data fields, which means you could anticipate all elements in your schema. Perhaps you have (or plan to introduce at some point) custom methods to process certain kinds of information? That, too, would not be possible with arbitrary content because it would be impossible to determine what kind of information was stored.

Comment: Haven't thought that far yet. but that is also an idea. Maybe some day ;)